# Why does my LED light take several minutes to come on?

Tags: switch, led, light

My led ceiling light does not come on straight away after switch on. It can take anything from 5 to 20 mins to illuminate. It does come on eventually. I have two separate switches to turn on this one light in different locations in my lounge ( thought I’d mention this in case it’s relevant).

Thank you for any advice

Comment: Is either switch a dimmer? Has the fixture ever worked properly?

Comment: Hi no dimmer. It did work properly

Comment: Then it would seem that the circuitry is failing. Unless you tell us more about the thing, what can we say?

Comment: Thanks. Apologies if I haven’t been specific enough

Comment: The thing to note is that LED lighting is much different than conventional bulbs. It has circuitry that varies between manufacturers and models, so if we don't know what we're dealing with it's difficult to help.

Comment: It went faulty when my boys were messing with the switches, turning them on and off in quick succession... at the two switch locations in the lounge if that makes sense

Comment: What make and model is the fixture in question?

Answer (score 1):

The driver circuitry May have been damaged or had cold solder joints that are failing.

The led dimmed or not should be almost immediate.

I have had drivers that had cold solder joints on very high end fixtures that caused the fixture to take longer to light to start with and a while later it would not light at all as these fixtures were almost 500 ea I figured out the problem and it a bad solder joint (I don’t have to mention where the fixtures were made but it was not the US)

If you still have a warranty I would recommend trying that route because if any LED won’t light in under a second something is wrong.

I would also recommend getting DLC approved lamps or fixtures DLC is design Light Consortium and they usually have a 5 year warranty (some 3 year) .
All the ones I have seen also have UL listing (I have to have this for industrial or another nationally recognized 3rd party facility).

Since the lights are taking more than a second there is a problem it could be a loose wire can be a possibility. My experience has been bad drivers on almost 100% of my failures.